# Convert it to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this line of code:

```
$search = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM list WHERE ID= '$name' ");
```

And I want do it like this:

```
$example = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM list (ID) VALUES (?)');
```

But the problem is that I need enter the part `"mysqli_query($mysqli,"`, how can I add it to my second line of code¿?

Comment: I suggest you read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Also see [PHP Done Right](https://phptherightway.com/#databases).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes

Comment: @ALEX sorry, I deleted my comment to see if you were checking to see if a row exists, then I saw your comment under Barmar's answer. Consult the duplicate, it's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

SQL syntax doesn't change when you use prepared statements. You just replace the variable with a placeholder.

```
$statement = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE ID= ? ");
$statement->bind_param("s", $name);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Don't work doing it

Comment: What part of it isn't working?

Comment: Then I try use the second code with mysqli_num_rows and no work doing it with prepared statements

Comment: Read a tutorial on mysqli prepared statements, you don't read the results the same way. You have to use `$statement->bind_result()`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: No work colleague

Comment: Describing the observed behavior as "don't work" or "no work" is practically *useless* in providing any meaningful information about the actual behavior that is observed. Barmar answered the question that was asked. Don't muck with `mysqli_num_rows`. Just do a fetch, and check if that's successful. Id we need a count of the number of rows, then we can increment a counter in a fetch loop. Also ditch the `*` in the SELECT list and explicitly list the expressions to be returned. If all we need is a count, we can use a COUNT() aggregate in the SELECT list, and get the value from the fetched row.